# Selenium C#, IList<IWebElement> Iterate through and Assert Values

Tags: c#, linq, list, selenium, assert

Any help would be appreciated.

Firstly, I'm using pageObject, and I have the following element.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using = ".//*[@id='control-content']/div/tbody/th")]    
public IList<IWebElement> TableHeaders { get; set; }
```

In this Ilist it should collect all values within the main column header.

I instantiate the class in the relevant page for script.

```
pageModule pm = new PageModule();
```

In the relevant page. I call the element.

```
var values = pm.TableHeaders;
```

Then I I set a list

```
List<String> nameFilters = new List<String>(){
"Name",
"Name2",
}

foreach(var value in Values){
  Console.WriteLine("The value is : ") + values);
}
```

This is for the outputting the text in the ilist, I want to check the values match the Ilist and The string list.

I want to iterate through the list of these and check that list contains these values, I know you can use LINQ to make this query simple, I just can't think of an easy idea at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using NUnit?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution worked...

```
 var value = pm.TableHeaders;

        List<string> nameFilters = new List<string>()
        {
            "Name",
            "Name2",
        };
        List<string> text = value.Select(x => x.Text).Where(columnName => columnName != "").ToList();

        return nameFilters.SequenceEqual(text);
```